# Having no success calling SetPolicies via SOAP SSRS 2010 API

Tags: soap, reporting-services

I'm having a heck of a time calling SetPolicies() ([API ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.setpolicies%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) using the 2010 SSRS WSDL (on SQL Server 2008R2 SSRS Server).  When I POST with the following payload, I get a 200 response, a well formed SOAP response with an empty body, but no policy actually created for the given folder.

I'm making other calls successfully, so I'm not worried about auth problems.  Additionally, I've made the same calls via Powershell with success.

I'm trying to use the raw SOAP API (called from Ruby actually)...anybody have any suggestions on what to try next?

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer"
              xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <tns:SetPolicies>
      <tns:ItemPath>/mydir</tns:ItemPath>
      <tns:Policies>
        <tns:groupUserName>mydomain\someuser</tns:groupUserName>
        <tns:roles>
          <tns:role>
            <tns:name>Content Manager</tns:name>
            <tns:description>stuff</tns:description>
          </tns:role>
          <tns:role>
            <tns:name>Browser</tns:name>
            <tns:description>stuff here too</tns:description>
          </tns:role>
        </tns:roles>
      </tns:Policies>
    </tns:SetPolicies>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  I was able to catch the POST powershell is using (via wireshark) and look at the XML...the tags are identical, except for casing...

Looks like the reportServer API is sensitive to the case of the XML tags...when POSTing this, I get a 200, and the policies are actually set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer"
              xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <tns:SetPolicies>
      <tns:ItemPath>/mydir</tns:ItemPath>
      <tns:Policies>
        <tns:GroupUserName>mydomain\someuser</tns:groupUserName>
        <tns:Roles>
          <tns:Role>
            <tns:Name>Content Manager</tns:name>
            <tns:Description>stuff</tns:description>
          </tns:Role>
          <tns:Role>
            <tns:Name>Browser</tns:name>
            <tns:Description>stuff here too</tns:description>
          </tns:Role>
        </tns:Roles>
      </tns:Policies>
    </tns:SetPolicies>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```